# Background Color Size fit with Text?

Tags: html, css

See [my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByjxwV). I look to make the blue background color scale to fit with the text, "My Pet". I tried `display: inline` and `padding`, but I couldn't figure out how to set the background to fit with the text responsively, rather than being full width. Also, how can I set the opacity of the background color but not the text?

After googling, I still struggle to find a solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bgImage">
        <h1>My Pet</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myDiv h1 {
    font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.5em; 
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #2ba6cb;  
/*  padding: 0.5em 0.2em 0.8em 0.5em;*/
}
```

Comment: Provide what you have tried thus far.

Comment: yes, I add codePen example :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is [**this**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/QwyrmY) what you're trying to achieve?

```css
.myDiv {
  text-align: center;
}

.myDiv h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(43, 166, 203, 0.5 /* alpha value for background */);
  padding: 0.5em 0.2em 0.8em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <h1>My Pet</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes Ana, that's what I am looking for.  Appreciate it.

Comment: I want to add Vote Up for all these replies, but require 15 reputations, sigh.

Answer (score 2):

even shorter

```
width: max-content;
```

```css
.myDiv h1 {
    font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.5em; 
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #2ba6cb; 
    width:max-content; 
    padding:2px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bgImage">
        <h1>My Pet</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you were trying to get? This way you can set opacity of bgImage

```css
.myDiv h1 {
    font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.5em; 
}

.myDiv {
  text-align:center;
}

.myDiv .bgImage{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #2ba6cb;
      border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.2em 0.8em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bgImage">
        <h1>My Pet</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just display your h1 as a table-cell and add the required padding around the text.

Note the last two rules to selector below....

```
.myDiv h1 {
    font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.5em; 
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #2ba6cb;  
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 0.5em ;
}
```