# Text background color css

Tags: css

How to shorten the background color left over from the text?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Erx.png)

Css

```
    p {
    background-color: #CC3340;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following:

```
  width:fit-content;
  padding: .5rem;
```

I advice you to have a look at [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-min-content-max-content-fit-content-css/) for more details about the difference between `min-content`, `max-content`, and `fit-content`.

**EDIT** I believe your question is the same as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368928/background-color-size-fit-with-text), the answer uses a different approach.